# How to convert string to bitmap image

Tags: c#, wpf

please tell me how to convert  text or string in bitmap image in wpf in c#.because there is no bitmap class is available like windows form..
 Thanks for Advance :)

Comment: You can still use the bitmap class from WinForms in WPF by adding reference to `System.Drawing` to your project and then accessing the class through `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

[**BitmapImage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for. Refer to the sample provided in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx) link.

```
// Create the image element.
Image simpleImage = new Image();    
simpleImage.Width = 200;
simpleImage.Margin = new Thickness(5);

// Create source.
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block.
bi.BeginInit();
bi.UriSource = new Uri(@"/sampleImages/cherries_larger.jpg",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
bi.EndInit();
// Set the image source.
simpleImage.Source = bi;
```

---

Also, you can set the source directly in XAML which WPF internally convert to ImageSource via default converter for String to ImageSource.

```
<Image Source="/sampleImages/cherries_larger.jpg"/>
```